# ¿Cómo redondear decimales en Java Script?

Tags: javascript, decimal

Estoy realizando una página que ayuda a calcular la hidratación basal. Necesito que mi resultado se convierta de decimales a enteros, ya que al cargar mi resultado en la pagina me sale con muchísimos decimales.

Les dejo el código aquí.
Les agradecería mucho si alguien me puede ayudar

```javascript
vd = (res / 24);
mant = (vd * 1.5);

// Mostrar los resultados en la página
FLU.innerHTML = vd + "cc/h";
MAN.innerHTML = "m+m/2 : " + mant + "cc/h";
```

Comment: Hiciste tan siquiera una simple búsqueda en google de "redondeo números javascript" por ejemplo? Porque según las reglas de SO se debe investigar (y demostrar) antes de hacer una pregunta, y tu pregunta no tiene investigación ninguna puesto que además es algo que tiene cientos de resultados en cualquier simple búsqueda en google, además de buena documentación. Por no hablar de que aprender a investigar es el 90% del trabajo de un programador, es una habilidad que deberías coger y practicar cuanto antes... preguntar en SO debe ser un último recurso para un programador, y no lo primero que hace.

Answer (score 4):

Tienes varios métodos

- `Math.round`: Redondea al entero más cercano
- `Math.trunc`: Devuelve la parte entera, removiendo los decimales
- `Math.ceil`: Redondea al entero mayor más próximo
- `Math.floor`:Redondea al entero menor más próximo
- `toFixed(cantidad_decimales)`: Devuelve un número redondeando como `string`, si el argumento es `0` o no tiene argumento devolverá solo la parte entera

```js
let x=3.10;
let y=3.90;
let z=3.5;

console.log("Func ","X","Y", "Z");
console.log("================");
console.log("round",Math.round(x),Math.round(y),Math.round(z));
console.log("trunc",Math.trunc(x),Math.trunc(y),Math.trunc(z));
console.log("ceil",Math.ceil(x),Math.ceil(y),Math.ceil(z));
console.log("floor",Math.floor(x),Math.floor(y),Math.floor(z));
console.log("toFixed",x.toFixed(),y.toFixed(),z.toFixed());
```

---

A pedido del publico agrego los operadores binarios, el truco es que javascript convierte automáticamente los argumentos de una operación binaria en entero (eliminando la parte decimal, como los hace `Math.floor`), entonces cualquier operación binaria que deje el número igual sirve (de forma análoga en operaciones en base 10, es como multiplicar por 1 o sumar cero).

```js
let x=3.14;
let y=4.99;

//Usando OR
console.log( x|0    ,y|0);

//Usando AND (con cualquier número que en binario sean todos 1 y mayor al número de la izquierda)
console.log( x&7 ,y&7);

//Doble negación
console.log( ~~x,~~y );
```

Comment: Y falto el redondeo por conversion binaria `x = x | 0`.

Comment: @Layer como es eso? si `x=3.1` => `let r = r | 0` = `3.1`

Comment: Lo ejecutaste en javascript?, a mi `3.10 | 0` me da 3 entero a dia de hoy

Comment: Comparto este post para quien esté interesado en lo que sugiere @Layer: [How does x|0 floor the number in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049677)

Comment: En tu respuesta pones "usando OR" pero eso no es un OR, el operador lógico OR es `||`. El operador `|` es el *bitwise operator OR*. No son lo mismo, no hacen lo mismo y no se llaman igual (aunque desconozco el nombre en español). Cuidado con confundir a la gente nueva :)

Comment: @Benito-B uno es *Logical OR* y el otro es *Bitwise OR*, ambos son `OR`

Comment: @Benito-B lo que dijo benito, y si, uno es logico y el otro es binario (bitwise).